# Why does .toString(16) convert rgb, decimal, or other inputs into a hexidecimal

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb

I've tried searching everywhere I could to find the answer as to why .toString(16) converts a number to a hexidecimal value. My first question is, why 16? My second question is, how can this return letters even though I see no letters going into the code. For example, I don't understand how the following code returns ff instead of a number.

```js
var r = 255;
r.toString(16); //returns ff
```

If anyone has any links or insights as to why this is, please let me know. I'm very curious. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because that is what it's meant to do. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString).

Comment: Because colors hex like `#ffffff` comes from the RGB values combined to issue a color. so 255,255,255 will create `ffffff` combined.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hexadecimal is base 16. Break down the words: hexa, meaning 6; decimal, meaning 10. 10 + 6 = 16. A few major bases are:

- Base 2: Binary, 2 numbers: [0, 1]
- Base 8: Octal, 8 numbers: [0, 7]
- Base 10: Decimal, 10 numbers: [0, 9]
- Base 16: Hexadecimal, 16 symbols: [0, 9] and [A, F]

---

Per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString):

> For `Number` objects, the `toString()` method returns a string representation of the object in the specified radix.
>
> Parameters
>
> **radix**:
>   Optional. An integer between 2 and 36 specifying the base to use for representing numeric values.

This means it converts the number into a string, and based on the radix. The syntax for `Number.prototype.toString` is:

```
number.toString([radix])
```

Where `radix` is optional. If you specify the radix, it will convert with that base, so 16 is hexadecimal. If `radix` is not specified, 10 (decimal) is assumed. Here's a snippet:

```js
var num = 16;

console.log(num.toString()) //"16", base 10 is assumed here if no radix given
console.log(num.toString(16)) //"10", base 16 is given
```

Now, regarding RGB values: take (255, 255, 255) [white] as an example. Each individual value (red, green, or blue) is represented in hex. Since 255 is `0xFF` or simply `FF` in hex, the full representation is `FFFFFF`, or `ffffff` you see.

Comment: @atrev No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using 16 as the radix, as explained here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

If you are just trying to get back `"16"`you can just do:

```
var number = 16;
var numberAsString = number.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

In returns a 'String' since `toString()` is set to return a `String`.

In addition, it is `toString(16)` because hexadecimal means 16 and it is base 16. Therefore, `toString(16)` converts a given variable into a `String` in a desired form, in this case you want it to be in the hexadecimal form.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

> Parameter: radix
>
> Description: Optional. Which base to use for representing a numeric
>   value. Must be an integer between 2 and 36.
>
> - 2 - The number will show as a binary value
> - 8 - The number will show as an octal value
> - 16 - The number will show as an hexadecimal value
>
> Example Convert a number to a string, using different bases:
>
> ```
> var num = 15;
> var a = num.toString();
> var b = num.toString(2);
> var c = num.toString(8);
> var d = num.toString(16);
> ```
>
> The result of a,b,c, and d will be:
>
> ```
> 15
> 1111
> 17
> f
> ```